# Questions about the formula used to determine inductive reactance and $Z_t$

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

I am currently on the inductors unit in my Navy schooling and I have two questions about these formulas that I learned about. As I'm aware, the ability of an inductor to concentrate a magnetic field is called an inductance. Inductive reactance measures the amount of opposition to the current flow in the circuit and is expressed as :

$X_L = 2\pi fL$ where $f$ is the frequency and $L$ represents the ohmic value from the inductor. I am not sure why we are multiplying by $2\pi$ here. The formula makes sense since frequency and current affects the inductor.

My other question has to do with this strange formula for $Z_t$ the total ohmic value of the resistors and inductors in a series parallel circuit:

$$ Z_t = \frac{R \times X_L}{\sqrt{R^2 + X_{L}^2}}$$

Here $R$ represents the total resistance value and $X_L$ represents the total inductive value. I'm puzzled as to where this formula comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In electric linear circuits theory, use is made of [phasors to represent sinusoidal inputs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) (most common basic inputs to linear circuits).

For **linear circuits** the total output of a given input is just the sum of each output component associated with each input component (provided there is a way to decompose any given input to compoents) (this is the definition of a **linear system**)

i.e by definition a **linear system** $L$ has this property:

$$L \left( av_1 + bv_2\right) = aL(v_1)+bL(v_2)$$

(the output of the sum of inputs equals the sum of the outputs of each input)

The way to decompose the input is by using [fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) (effectively representing each input as a sum of sinusoidal signals)

So one sees now how the phasors make the analysis of any circuit simpler.

So, in this format, the resistance $R$ is just $R$. If one wants to combine inductors and capacitos in the phasor representation then the combined resistance is refered as [impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) and allows to treat both inductors and capacitors as **complex resistances** (under a given frequency $f$)

Then the usual Ohm's laws and series/parallel formulas for resistors can be applied using instead the complex impendances stemming from analysing the input in phasors.

UPDATE:

The $X_L = 2\pi fL$ is actually $X_L = \omega L$ but $\omega = 2 \pi f$